# not accurate setTimeout and it works only on mousedown

Tags: facebook, settimeout, mousedown

I have problem with setTimeout.

In all major browsers it works fine but not in IE...
I'm creating a facebook app- puzzle. When player press Start button, the timer starts count his time of playing one game. 
At the beginning I used setInterval to increase timer but with cooperate of facebook scripts it delayed about 2 seconds at the end of game. Then I found on stackoverflow trick to increase accuracy of timer: [setInterval timing slowly drifts away from staying accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173580/setinterval-timing-slowly-drifts-away-from-staying-accurate)
And again- without facebook it worked fine, no delays were shown. With facebook it still has delays.
Now to condensate info that might interest You:
When user clicks Start then I create new Date as startTime.
When user ends game script creates finalTime new Date, then substract finalTime - startTime.

In code there is setTimeout:

```
(...)    

f : function() {
        var sec_time = Math.floor((puzzle.nextAt - puzzle.startTime)/1000);
        $('.timer').html(sec_time);
        if (!puzzle.startTime) {
            puzzle.startTime = new Date().getTime();
            puzzle.nextAt = puzzle.startTime;
            $('.timer').html('0');
        }
        puzzle.nextAt += 100;
        puzzle.to = setTimeout(puzzle.f, puzzle.nextAt - new Date().getTime());
    }

(...)
```

when user place on correct place last puzzle piece then I call clearTimeout(puzzle.to);

I have now 2 issues:

1. not accurate time, in IE it can be even 7 second difference!
2. in IE during game it works only when user have mousedown... :/

To drag puzzles I use jQuery drag & drop plugin.
At least very helpful info will be how to achieve accurate timer.

Comment: You could use a jQuery onReady to set your start time, and run a timer every (for example) 0.5 seconds to poll the difference between the start time and current time, for running a timer. If you set start time inline in the script, you have no guarantee for when it executes, especially when using multiple JS SDKs.

Comment: @Connor thanks for Your reply :) By 'You could use a jQuery onReady' did You mean that I should put script in $(document).ready(function() {...}); ? I have all my scripts (except JS SDK) at the bottom of page so they are loaded after all DOM elements but I'm not sure if I understand You correct. You propose run timer every 0.5s, as You can see in code I run timer every 100ms to calculate it so it's even better I think. Is there any way to 'cut out' that timer so it won't interfere with FB JS SDK and my drag&drop actions? Or is there any, better way to achieve what I want, that I don't know?

Comment: The jQuery part is correct. I'll add the rest as a possible answer based on the increased info above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your scripts in jQuery's ready function and not at the bottom of the page, as the Facebook SDK is loaded asynchronously and may impact timed executions if they're initiated at the bottom of the page.

As for timing, you're gonna see inaccuracy of between 15ms and 45ms in IE7 depending on other JS executions on the page. Your 100ms timeout will drift badly because of this. Better to record a start time and build a timer with a higher polling frequency than needed and do a comparison between start time and 'now' in each cycle to determine what to do next.

Comment: Great, thanks for help! I didn't know about that fact that despite that I have script at the bottom it might not run as I expect, like You said. I also modified my timer function like You said. Now, if script lags and the timer doesn't change numbers for a while, after 'unlag' number show correct number, not just +1 second. It's quite easy solution as I can see now :) Thanks again for help! Note: I noticed that in fact it isn't FB JS SDK causing slow down, it is drag&drop plugin.