# Run a Function For Each Milliseconds

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am trying to run a function for each milliseconds, In order to achieve so, I just preferred `setInterval` concept in javascript. My code is given below,

**HTML:**

```
<div id=test>0.0</div>
```

**Script:**

```
var xVal = 0;
var xElement = null;

xElement = document.getElementById("test");
var Interval = window.setInterval(startWatch, 1);


function startWatch(){

    xVal += 1;
    xElement.innerHTML = xVal;

}
```

so the above code is working fine. But while I am testing the result with a real clock, the real clock requires 1000 milliseconds to complete 1 second, at the same time the result require more than 1000 milliseconds to complete a second.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3hEs4/)**

Can anybody tell me,

Is there any mistakes with my code? If yes then tell me, How to display milliseconds accurately.?

Comment: The browser is not a realtime system and any segment of JS can take > 1 millisecond to complete. Using 1 millisecond intervals is not a good solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no mistakes in your code, but JavaScript timers (`setInterval` and `setTimeout`) [are not precise](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). Browsers cannot comply with such a short interval. So I'm afraid there is no way to *precisely* increment the milliseconds by one, and display the updates, on a web browser. In any case, that's not even visible to the human eye!

A precise *workaround* would involve a larger interval, and timestamps to calculate the elapsed time in milliseconds:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    xElement.innerHTML = (now - start) + 'ms elapsed';
}, 40);
```

Comment: Suppose if I want to simulate a Stop watch then that would be impossible with web applications.? Right.?

Comment: See my update. It's possible, what's not possible is to use a 1ms increment, and expect it to visually update. It's not even visible to the human eye anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.  There is a minimum delay that browsers use.  You cannot run a function every millisecond.

From Mozilla's docs:

> ...4ms is specified by the HTML5 spec and is consistent across browsers...

<sub>Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The DOM can't actually update `1000` times per second. Your monitor can't even display `1000` frames in one second, for that matter. Calculate the difference between the start time and current time in milliseconds within your function and use that:

```
(function(){
    var xElement = document.getElementById("test");
    var start = new Date;

    (function update(){
      xElement.innerHTML = (new Date - start);

      setTimeout(update, 0);
    })();
}();
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hEs4/2/)

Comment: +1 for using recursive `setTimeout` as opposed to `setInterval`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do so using your method because of the delay rendering the HTML and running the interval. Doing it this way will display the time correctly at about 60FPS.

http://jsfiddle.net/3hEs4/3/

```
var xElement = null;
var startTime = new Date();

xElement = document.getElementById("test");
var Interval = window.setInterval(startWatch, 17);


function startWatch(){
     var currentTime = new Date();
     xElement.innerHTML = currentTime - startTime;   
}
```

You might also want to look into using requestanimationframe instead of a hardcoded setInterval like that.

Comment: Is there any reason for hardcoding that 17.?

Comment: Yeah, the time between frames with 60FPS is 1000/60 ~= 16.67ms. Rounded up to 17.

Comment: you can use simply 1000/60 as argument instead of hardcoded 17 :)

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` callback probably does not happen with millisecond accuracy, since the thread the timer is running on might not even actually be running when the time is up, or the browser throttles events, or any other of quite a few things.

In addition, since most Javascript engines are single threaded, what the implementation of `setInterval` might do is once it triggers, run your callback, and then reset the clock for the next call. Since you're doing some DOM manipulation, that might take several milliseconds on its own.

In short, you're expecting a Real Time Operating System behavior from an interpreter running inside of another application, on top of what is more than likely not an RTOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and couldn't find any working solution, so I created one myself. The code below essentially calls five `setTimout`s every 5 ms, for each ms between 5 and 10. This circumvents the minimum 4 ms constraint, and (having checked in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera) works fairly well.

```
const start = performance.now();
let newNow = 0;
let oldNow = 0;

const runner = function(reset) {
    // whatever is here will run ca. every ms
    newNow = performance.now();
    console.log("new:", newNow);
    console.log("            diff:", newNow - oldNow);
    oldNow = newNow
    if (newNow - start < 1000 && reset) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            runner(true);
        }, 5);
        for (let i = 6; i < 11; i++) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                runner(false);
            }, i);
        }
    }
};
runner(true);
```

It could of course be written more elegantly, e.g. so that you can more easily customize things like the graduation (e.g. 0.5 ms or 2 ms instead of 1 ms), but anyway the principle is there.

I know that in theory you could call 5 `setInterval`s instead, but that would in reality cause a [drift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173580/) that would quickly ruin the ms precision.

Note also that there are legitimate cases for the use. (I for one need continual measurement of touch force, which is not possible otherwise.)