# Javascript function execution on real time clock new minute

Tags: javascript, interrupt, clock, timing

I'm looking for an efficient (not continuous polling) way to execute a function whenever the real time clock turns over to a new minute. My current code uses setInterval to call the function every 60 seconds -- but in practice there is some lagging and the function is getting called at about 60.2 seconds on average. This is leading to a cumulative error that builds up in a process monitoring system I'm developing.

Does anyone out there have a clever bit of code that calls a function at regular intervals triggered by the real time clock?

Edit: I was alerted to a method to compensate for the error by checking the time each time the function was called and compensating the setInterval value for the next call. This gets me closer -- but what I'm really after is a method to call a function right at the start of a new minute according to the real time clock...

Comment: possible duplicate of [setInterval timing slowly drifts away from staying accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173580/setinterval-timing-slowly-drifts-away-from-staying-accurate)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29971898/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you use `setInterval` with an interval of 1 minute, it will eventually start to drift, as you've observed.  You don't have to continuously poll, though: you just have to use chained calls to `setTimeout`.  Each one checks itself against the clock.  Sometimes the timeout will be 59999, sometimes it will be 59997, etc.  But it will always be keeping in step with the clock.

```
function everyMinuteOnTheMinute() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var d = new Date();
        console.log(d.getMinutes() + " (" + d.valueOf() % 1000 + ")");
        // your "every minute" code goes here
        everyMinuteOnTheMinute();
    }, 60000 - Date.now() % 60000);
}
```

You can turn this into a general utility by adding a callback:

```
function everyMinuteOnTheMinute(cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb();
        everyMinuteOnTheMinute(cb);
    }, 60000 - Date.now() % 60000);
}
```

Then when you have code you need to run every minute on the minute, just use the utility function:

```
everyMinuteOnTheMinute(function() {
    console.log("Whee, I'm happening every minute on the minute!");
});
```

Comment: `everyMinute` is not a function… Did you mean to recursively call something?

Comment: Yes, I did, thanks for the catch, Bergi.  I decided to rename it so that it's more explicit (`everyMinute` doesn't necessarily mean "on the minute"), but forgot to change the invocation,