# function inside setinterval takes more than timeout

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a synchronous function inside setInterval() where I have set the timeout to 1 second. At times, the synchronous function inside setInterval() takes 30+ seconds to execute. Meaning, the function defined inside setInterval() is taking more than timeout set. Recently, I have been facing lot of issues inside this function which im not able to track.

Can anyone tell me **if it is a problem when function inside setInterval takes more than the timeout**? Or **if theres any other ideal way to keep on calling a function whose execution time is unpredictable**?

**Sample Code:**

```
myFunction = async()=>{
 // Some synchronous external API calls which takes 30+ seconds to execute
}    
setInterval(myFunction,1000)
```

Comment: can you please show the code, you are having trouble with?

Comment: AFAIK, setInterval is NOT guaranteed to run at the exact timing set. It will wait AT LEAST the set timing before it executes. It depends on how many tasks are running. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173580/setinterval-timing-slowly-drifts-away-from-staying-accurate

Comment: Looking at myFunc(), it will obviously take 30+ seconds for setInterval to execute. It needs to wait for the micro task (the network call) to complete. Hence, the 1 second interval set is meaningless.

Comment: @Argee I have updated my question with sample code. The original code Im trying to execute is huge, which is why I have posted a similar minimalist code. Hope it helps

Comment: `myFunction` is *not* synchronous.

Comment: You probably want to `setTimeout(myFunction, 1000)` *at the end of `myFunction`*. Meaning, you let it call itself again after a timeout after it has finished executing.