# Timer did not reach zero javascript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to complete the FreeCodeCamp 25 + 5 clock project with React. When I website runs the project tests, it says that the timer is not reaching 00:00, even though when I click play, it clearly reaches 00:00.

I am wondering if I am having this issue because of some sort of drifting? How would I go about fixing that?

Thank you.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Jamece/pen/jOazYvQ

I also tried a version where i use SetTimeout and implement this Stack overflow answer ([setInterval timing slowly drifts away from staying accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173580/setinterval-timing-slowly-drifts-away-from-staying-accurate)), but it still wouldn't pass the test. See that codepen: https://codepen.io/Jamece/pen/mdqGomq

I also tried delaying the this.atZero function 1 second and that didn't work

My Code:

```
const minTime = 1;
const maxTime = 60;

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breakLength: .1,
      sessionLength: .1,
      started: false,
      mode: "Session",
      intervalId: "",
      timeLeft: .1
    };
    this.breakIncrement = this.breakIncrement.bind(this);
    this.breakDecrement = this.breakDecrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionIncrement = this.sessionIncrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionDecrement = this.sessionDecrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionTimer = this.sessionTimer.bind(this);
    this.breakTimer = this.breakTimer.bind(this);
    this.pause = this.pause.bind(this);
    this.timers = this.timers.bind(this);
    this.initialDisplay = this.initialDisplay.bind(this);
    this.switchMode = this.switchMode.bind(this);
    this.begin = this.begin.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
    this.atZero = this.atZero.bind(this);
  }

  initialDisplay() {
    let initialDisplay =
      this.state.sessionLength < 10
        ? "0" + this.state.sessionLength + ":" + "00"
        : this.state.sessionLength + ":" + "00";
    return initialDisplay;
  }

  begin() {
    this.setState({ started: !this.state.started });
    if (this.state.started) {
      this.pause();
    } else {
      if (this.state.mode == "Session") {
        this.sessionTimer();
      } else {
        this.breakTimer();
      }
    }
  }
  
  atZero(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("beep");
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
        this.switchMode();
        audio.play();
  }

  switchMode() {
    if (this.state.mode == "Session") {
      this.setState({
        mode: "Break",
        timeLeft: this.state.breakLength
      });
      this.breakTimer();
    } else if (this.state.mode == "Break") {
      this.setState({
        mode: "Session",
        timeLeft: this.state.sessionLength
      });
      this.sessionTimer();
    }
  }

  breakIncrement() {
    if (!this.state.started) {
      if (this.state.breakLength !== maxTime) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          breakLength: state.breakLength + 1
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  breakDecrement() {
    if (!this.state.started) {
      if (this.state.breakLength !== minTime) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          breakLength: state.breakLength - 1
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  sessionIncrement() {
    if (!this.state.started) {
      if (this.state.sessionLength !== maxTime) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          sessionLength: state.sessionLength + 1
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  sessionDecrement() {
    if (!this.state.started) {
      if (this.state.sessionLength !== minTime) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          sessionLength: state.sessionLength - 1
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  timers(length, display, paused) {
    var start = Date.now();
    const timer = () => {
      const distance = (length) - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
      var minutes = (distance / 60) | 0;
      var seconds = distance % 60 | 0;
      
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
      this.setState({ timeLeft: distance / 60 });
      const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
};
      if (distance < 0) {
        
        this.atZero();
       
      }
    };
   timer();
    var intervalId = setInterval(timer,1000);
    this.setState({
      intervalId: intervalId
    });
  }

  sessionTimer() {
    var length = this.state.timeLeft * 60;
    var display = document.getElementById("time-left");
    this.timers(length, display);
    this.setState({ started: true });
  }

  breakTimer() {
    var length = this.state.timeLeft * 60;
    var display = document.getElementById("time-left");
    this.timers(length, display);
    this.setState({ started: true });
  }

  pause() {
    if (this.state.intervalId) {
      clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }
    this.setState({ started: !this.state.started });
  }

  reset() {
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    this.setState({
      breakLength: 5,
      sessionLength: 25,
      started: false,
      mode: "Session",
      intervalId: "",
      timeLeft: 25
    });
    let resetValue = this.initialDisplay();
    let resetDisplay = document.getElementById("time-left");
    resetDisplay.textContent = resetValue;
    var audio = document.getElementById("beep");
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }

  render() {
    let pausePlayStyle = this.state.started
      ? "fa-solid fa-pause"
      : "fa-solid fa-play";
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid px-0">
        <div className="main d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <div className="heading">25 + 5 Clock</div>
            <div className="d-flex">
              <div className="d-flex flex-column break align-items-center">
                <div id="break-label" className="mb-3 h3">
                  Break Length
                </div>
                <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-top"
                    id="break-increment"
                    onClick={this.breakIncrement}
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>
                  </button>
                  <div className="mx-3 h3" id="break-length">
                    {this.state.breakLength}
                  </div>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-top"
                    id="break-decrement"
                    onClick={this.breakDecrement}
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center session">
                <div id="session-label" className="mb-3 h3">
                  Session Length
                </div>
                <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-top"
                    id="session-increment"
                    onClick={this.sessionIncrement}
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>
                  </button>
                  <div className="h3 mx-3" id="session-length">
                    {this.state.sessionLength}
                  </div>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-top"
                    id="session-decrement"
                    onClick={this.sessionDecrement}
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center timer-border">
              <div className="h2 mb-3 session" id="timer-label">
                {this.state.mode}
              </div>
              <div className="display-1 timer mb-4" id="time-left">
                {this.initialDisplay()}
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-bottom"
                  id="start_stop"
                  onClick={this.begin}
                >
                  <i className={pausePlayStyle}></i>
                </button>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-bottom"
                  id="reset"
                  onClick={this.reset}
                >
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-rotate"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <audio
          id="beep"
          preload ="auto"
          src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=12NsFWtJh3pBCqQ8gV62EZF3OevgAy8ff"
                    />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was the Date.now that was messing it up.
I removed that and removed the start variable and changed the distance variable to the following:

```
var distance = length + 1;
distance -= 1;
```