# Why does the timing of these different animations get slower and out of order over time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I have a Video that changes every few seconds with spinning animation + video getting small and big during the spinning.
But over time the timing gets out of order.

```
let degree = 720;
function rotateElement(){
    let spin = `rotate(${degree}deg)`;
    document.getElementById('myVideo').style.transform = spin;
    document.getElementById('myVideo').style.transitionDuration = "1s";
    degree += 720;
}

function smaller(){
    document.getElementById('myVideo').style.maxWidth = "10px";
    document.getElementById('myVideo').style.maxHeight = "10px";
    document.getElementById('myVideo').style.transitionDuration = "1s";
}

function bigger(){
    document.getElementById('myVideo').style.maxWidth = "30vw";
    document.getElementById('myVideo').style.maxHeight = "19vw";
    document.getElementById('myVideo').style.transitionDuration = "1s";
}


//setInterval(change, 5000);





window.onload = function () {
    setInterval(change, 5000);
    setInterval(rotateElement, 4900);
    setInterval(smaller, 4850);
    setInterval(bigger, 5050);
    
};
```

Comment: setInterval is not accurate. Why are you not using just css to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173580/setinterval-timing-slowly-drifts-away-from-staying-accurate

Comment: how can I make an Item spin every 5 seconds in css?

Comment: and change, get bigger,smaller every 5sec. . .

Comment: Why have you tagged node.js and ejs? They don't appear to be relevant to the question!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want the animation to do with the rotate, but this is the basic idea of just doing it in CSS.

```css
.test {
  background-color: yellow;
  /*animation: shrink 5s 3s ease infinite, rotate 50s steps(10, end) forwards infinite; */
  animation: shrink 5s 3s ease infinite, rotate 50s forwards infinite;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 19vh;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0%,
  65%,
  90%,
  100% {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 19vh;
  }
  70% {
    width: 14px;
    height: 10px;
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="test" src="http://placekitten.com/200/100">
```