# javascript countdown script from milliseconds in to hours-minutes-seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am looking for a easy way to output milliseconds into hours-minutes-seconds. I have seen some plugins but i dont want to use a plugin in a plugin, and I have seen a lot of countdown snippets but these are using the date, I am using not a date but milliseconds.

Thanks.

EDIT: i am looking for a script that counts back from xxxx milliseconds to zero

//until now i have this

```
    diff  = 100000000;

    function showTimer() {

        hours = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60) );
        mins  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60) );
        secs  = Math.floor( diff / 1000 );

        $('.count').html(hours+ 'hours' +minutes + 'minutes' +seconds + ' seconds');
    }

    setInterval(function(){showTimer()}, 1000 );
```

Comment: You will need to use Date for a reliable timer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple maths.

1000 milliseconds = 1 second.

60 seconds = 1 minute.

60 minutes = 1 hour.

So if you have 123456789 milliseconds, you'd do something like:

123456789 / 1000 (to seconds) which is 123456.789

123456.789 / 60 (to minutes) which is 2,057.6

2,057.6 / 60 (to hours) which is 34.29 hours.

Then use the remainder (.2935525) and turn this into minutes - which is 17.61315

Use the remainder again (.61315) and turn it to seconds... which is 36.789

So, in short, 123456789 milliseconds equals 34 hours, 17 minutes and 37 seconds.

I'm sure you can do the JavaScript part yourself.

---

Okay maybe you need some more help.

**DEMO** : http://jsbin.com/eqawam/edit#javascript,html,live

```
var millis = 123456789;

function displaytimer(){
    //Thank you MaxArt.
    var hours = Math.floor(millis / 36e5),
        mins = Math.floor((millis % 36e5) / 6e4),
        secs = Math.floor((millis % 6e4) / 1000);
        $('.count').html(hours+':'+mins+':'+secs);  
}

setInterval(function(){
    millis -= 1000;
    displaytimer();
}, 1000);
```

Also, for further reading - setInterval may drift. So don't expect this to be 100% accurate. [Will setInterval drift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985670/will-setinterval-drift)

Comment: i know the format, but i dont know how to make it dynamic ;-)

Comment: Thanks this what i am looking for. Yes i know its not accurate, but i can life with one or 2 seconds differents ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about what you're asking for, but...

```
var hours = Math.floor(millis / 36e5),
    mins = Math.floor((millis % 36e5) / 6e4),
    secs = Math.floor((millis % 6e4) / 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at : http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/

I have used this.

In Javascript you can do the following

```
        $('#counter_2').countdown({
      image: 'img/digits.png',
      startTime: '10:59',
      timerEnd: function(){
        alert('The Time Limit for the quiz has expired. Click OK to submit quiz');
        $('#submit_quiz_form').submit(); 
      },
      format: 'mm:ss'
    });
```

You can get the time using the functions shown above ... I needed a form to be submitted when the timer ends ... you can do something similar if needed