# Are there any disadvantages to using javascript setInerval with a long interval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm writing a web application (HTML/CSS/JS frontend, C# backend) where the users are expected to be on the same page for a while (usually longer than 10 minutes).  I would like to periodically check the server to see if the user's session has expired.  Is there any disadvantage to using setInterval with an interval of say, 2 - 5 minutes, to make an AJAX request to the server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no disadvantage.  However, the timer isn't the most accurate.  See also:  [Will setInterval drift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985670/will-setinterval-drift)  This may not matter to you, as it is a bigger problem for timers fired rapidly.  Plus, it doesn't soundl ike exact timing is a problem for you either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  You are correct, accuracy isn't a problem for me.  I just need it to happen roughly every few minutes.

Answer (score 6):

There is no problem in doing that. There will be a performance issue only when you don't keep the interval ids and run a number of intervals simultaneously (especially when the delay is very less). To prevent this you can clear the current interval before creating a new one. This makes sure that there is only required interval is live.

```
clearInterval(intervalID);
intervalID = setInterval(function(){
   ...
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I figured: multiple concurrent timers present performance issues.  Just wanted to be sure!