# Node.js setInterval() stops executing after 25 days

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

In my Node.js application, I use `setInterval()` to run a specific function every 1 hour. The function is executed properly for about 25 days, then the timer stops firing.

25 days seems awfully close to Node.js's [`TIMEOUT_MAX`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/timers.js#L21) (2^31 milliseconds ≈ 25 days), but I don't really see why `setInterval()` should stop executing after that time.

Update:

I think this may have been caused by the following bug in Node.js: [setInterval callback function unexpected halt #22149](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22149)

Comment: Have you tried using a recursive `setTimeout` instead?

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826266/nodejs-settimout-loop-stopped-after-many-weeks-of-iterations/51826893

Comment: Could you use something like `cron` / `schtasks` / some other OS-level scheduler instead?

Comment: @user202729 thanks, that indeed seems to be the same problem.

Comment: @Phil I could use `cron`, although that would require some additional logic in my application. I was hoping there may be some easy fix for `setInterval()`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I haven't, but the question linked by @user202729 suggests that `setTimeout` has the exact same problem.

Comment: Does anything else in your node.js process remain active and working?  Or is the `setInterval()` the only thing it's doing.  It could be that your whole process becomes unresponsive perhaps because of a memory or resource leak.

Comment: @jfriend00 the process is fine, only the timer stops working. I think this may be a bug in Node.js, I updated my question.

Comment: maybe you can use [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron), too.

Comment: @NoobTW I don't know about *node-cron*, but we were using *node-schedule* before and had the exact same problem. Anyway, it seems it's been fixed in Node.js now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the bug ([#22149](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22149)) has been fixed in [Node.js 10.9.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V10.md#10.9.0).

It may be also worth noting that this bug seems to be influencing **both** `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` (as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826266/nodejs-settimout-loop-stopped-after-many-weeks-of-iterations/)), so the workaround with `setTimeout()` in the callback function wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the issue in github, I think they will fix it in the next release. If you need to work around before that, you can try recursive timeout instead. Checkout my code:

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log('test');
}

function doSomethingInterval() {
   doSomething();
   setTimeout(doSomethingInterval, 1000);
}

doSomethingInterval();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug. Your easiest workaround is to use setTimeout instead, and then in your callback function call another setTimeout.