# How do I make setState work inside setInterval? (currently working-ish)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

```js
function func(){
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);
  var timeRemaining = 10;
  const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (timeRemaining > 0) {
        timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1;
        setTime(timeRemaining);
      } else { clearInterval(myInterval) }
    }, 1000);
  return <div>{time}</div>
}
```

The code above works thanks to the variable `timeRemaining`. However, it stops working if I remove that variable (in order to keep the code clean):

```js
const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (time> 0) { setTime(time-1); } 
    else { clearInterval(myInterval); }
  }, 1000);
```

By rewriting it in the above way, it stops updating `time`.

Comment: `setTime(currentTime => currentTime - 1)`. But honestly, [don't manage time yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20618355/1218980). Use `Date.now()` and do the math using the start time.

Comment: Also, see: [Will `setInterval` drift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/985670/1218980)

Answer (score 4):

Use effects to control interval, ref to hold reference to interval timer reference, and functional state update to correctly manage state.

- Effect 1 - setup (mount) and cleanup (unmount) of interval effect
- Effect 2 - clears interval when time reaches 0

Functional Component Code:

```
function App() {
  const timerRef = useRef(null);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Use pure functional state update to correctly queue up state updates
    // from previous state time value.
    // Store returned interval ref.
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => setTime(t => t - 1), 1000);

    // Return effect cleanup function
    return () => clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }, []); // <-- Empty dependency array, effect runs once on mount.

  useEffect(() => {
    // Clear interval and nullify timer ref when time reaches 0
    if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
      timerRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [time]); // <-- Effect runs on mount and when time value updates.

  return <div>{time}</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit focused-mendeleev-2cezr]

Answer (score 0):

Use the function version of setTime, though I'd suggest putting your interval into a useEffect for cleanup as well

```
  setTime((time) => {
    if (time > 0) {
      return time - 1;
    }
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    return time;
  });
```

With a useEffect for cleanup of the interval on unmount:

```js
const {useState,useEffect} = React;    
    
    function Func() {
      const [time, setTime] = useState(10);
      useEffect(() => {
        const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
          setTime((time) => {
            if (time > 0) {
              return time - 1;
            }
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            return time;
          });
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
          clearInterval(myInterval);
        };
      }, []);

      return <div>{time}</div>;
    }
    
 ReactDOM.render(<Func />,document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're creating a new `setInterval` every time the component was recreated, as a consequence of `setTime` execution.

As an alternative to the other answers, that put the `setInterval` calling inside an `useEffect`, you can also switch to a `setTimeout` and not using the `useEffect`:

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (time > 0) {
      setTime(time - 1);
    }
  }, 1000);

  return <div>{time}</div>;
};
```

Every time the component is redrawn as an effect of `setTime` call, the `setTimeout` will be fired again.

Comment: This can have issues if the component is ever re-rendered from a parent.

Comment: @ZacharyHaber, could you elaborate it a little bit? I'm very used to angular, but a complete newbie regarding react and I'd like to understand the problem here. BTW, if the explanation is too long for a comment and you can just link to some blog or article talking about it, I'll be glad.

Comment: Essentially the issue is that whenever a component re-renders, it also re-renders it's children. Since you have the setTimeout in the render function, if the App re-renders, then it'll start up a new timer. That new timer will actually setTime to what it would be currently, so react won't keep re-rendering over again. But you can have the timer function run more often than you would expect. https://codesandbox.io/s/timer-fun-rfzeg Play around with this, but keep in mind that StrictMode is on, which will re-render everything twice.

Comment: Thanks for the nice demo!

Comment: The other issue is when the component unmounts for any reason the timeout will expire and try to set state of an unmounted component. React will display a warning for this in non-production builds. You'll want to clean up any asynchronous code when components unmount.

Answer (score -1):

```
 function func(){
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);
  var timeRemaining = 10;
  const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
                    if (timeRemaining > 0) {
                        timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1;
                        setTime(timeRemaining);
                    } else { clearInterval(myInterval) }
                }, 1000);
   return <div>{time}</div>
 }
```

Here with every `render`, JS would start a `setInterval`. And in setInterval's callback, variable `timeRemaining` allocated for every `render` in respect get stored, or we call it `CLOSURE`. So `1 sec` after the very beginning, REACT render `func` again. And thus you get another `interval` and a variable `timeRemaining`. It'll run from `timeRemaining = 10`.

`setTime` will always be one thing. And `time` will be read from HOOKS's pools.

This code is WRONG! You'll have more and more `interval` with its `timeRemaining`.